# About sector and blocks, and a little confusion in /proc/diskstats

Tags: filesystems, proc

I've been studying about diskstats lately, and I get that the amount of hdd read comes in sectors. But in most places I've noticed that there exists a slight misunderstanding about sectors and blocks. So, what type is this sector which is read by the diskstats? Can I figure it out with:

```
dumpe2fs /dev/sda7 | grep 'Block size'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

blocks are logical "groups" or sequences of space. Usually 1 block = 4096 bytes.  They represent the smallest amount of space that can be reserved for a file. ie. you have a 12 byte file, your filesystem is still going to reserve a whole block (4096 bytes default for ext3)

sectors refers to a physical ring on the HDD (think of the grooves on a vinyl record)

To answer your question the command you ran will show the block size of that partition.

Comment: Thanks, h3rrmiller, you answer my question. I would vote in your answer, but i have not my 15 point to do it.